# Input group with flex box

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a Chrome extension so I can use bleeding-edge technologies like flexbox:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VhZS5/14/)

**HTML:**

```html
<label for="example-search">Classic search example</label>
<div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="example-search" />
    <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

**CSS (cleared to highlight flexbox):**

```css
.input-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.input-wrapper > input {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.input-wrapper > button {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is this the right way to work with flexbox?
2. Is there is a way to gracefully degrade this to use in websites?

Using flexbox for production:

I recently found a great article about my issue: [flexbox in the real world](http://www.planningforaliens.com/blog/2014/03/11/real-world-flexbox/)

Raw insigsts from atricle:

- use autoprefixer to support all old desktop and mobile browsers (they use old flexbox model syntax)
- use progressive enhancement for IE8- (see [Scenario 3](http://www.planningforaliens.com/blog/2014/03/11/real-world-flexbox/#scenario_3_you_have_to_support_ie8_but_it_doesnt_have_to_look_as_nice) from article)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you're overwriting properties set elsewhere, there's no reason for this line because this is the default for all flex containers:

```
flex-flow: row nowrap;
```

If your goal is to make this work on browsers with either of the old Flexbox implementations, there are 2 things to be aware of:

- The March 2012 draft (IE10) does not have individual properties for flex-grow, flex-shrink, or flex-basis.  The only way to control them is via the flex shorthand.
- The original draft does not allow you to have differing flex-shrink and flex-grow values.  It would be ok to translate `flex: 1 1 auto` to `box-flex: 1`, but you can't translate something like `flex: 1 0` (with prefixes).  For your purpose, `box-flex: 0` should work (though you might have problems with buttons in old Webkit browsers, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961192/flexbox-doesnt-work-with-buttons).

Comment: Thanks, @cimmanon.  
 Do you have any example for production ready solution?  
  
 It's not hard to add some old properties and add flexbox model v. 2009 for old Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Mobile, but what to do with IE?

Comment: You've already shown you know how to use the flex shorthand, I didn't think I needed to add it:  `flex: 0 1 auto` instead of `flex-shrink: 0`.

Comment: I prefer to use property directly for clarifying what i want to achieve. `flex-shrink: 0` explicitly says to me that button wouldn't shrink.

Comment: Er, guess I meant `flex: 1 0 auto`.  Unfortunately, you don't have a choice if you want to cover all of your bases:  IE10 doesn't have a flex-shrink property, you *have* to use flex instead.